# Is it possible to click a button on a html page from a separate html page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, django, web

I have two custom html pages: 
 'first.html' and
 'second.html'.
In 'second.html' I have a hidden div. I want to click a button on 'first.html' that will unhide the div in 'second.html'. I want both pages to be open at the same time in different windows/tabs.

This is a Django project so I tried to create a def in views.py that will open 'second.html' when the button on 'first.html' is opened. Doing this will just open 'second.html', but I need both pages to be opened at the same time.

Answer (score 2):

This sounds a bit weird, but sure. I can think of two ways to do it:

1. Have `first.html` open `second.html` using `window.open()`. This gives `first.html` full access to the DOM of `second.html`.
2. Communicate through the server. `first.html` tells the server the button has been clicked. `second.html` is listening, maybe with [EventSource](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventSource) and updates it's DOM.